# Insering null values in the triggering table

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I have a trigger query,

```
create or replace trigger trg_upd
 after update or delete or insert
  on dept for each row
 declare
 --pragma autonomous_transaction;
 begin
  if inserting then
  insert into deptemp values(:old.deptno,:old.dname,:old.loc);
  elsif updating then
 insert into deptemp values(:old.deptno,:old.dname,:old.loc);
 else
 insert into deptemp values(:old.deptno,:old.dname,:old.loc);
 end if;
end trg_upd;
```

and created table

```
create table deptemp as(select * from dept where 1=2);
```

When I am insering in the dept table  null values are inserting in the deptemp table

```
insert into dept values(50,'OLTP','Hyd');
```

Select * from deptemp;

```
DEPTNO DNAME          LOC                                                                       
------ -------------- -------------                                                             
    20 RESEARCH       DALLAS                                                                    
    30 SALES          CHICAGO                                                                   
    40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON                                                                    

    50 OLTP           Hyd                                                                       

    10 SALES          CHICAGO
```

Why the values inserted in the dept tables inserting as null values deptemp table?

Comment: Because you are using the "old" values, and for an insert there were no "old" values so they are null.  Use "new" if you want the new values.

Answer (score 0):

As Tony commented, in triggers, the `OLD` pseudorecord will have NULL as the value [when Inserting](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#LNPLS99955), because obviously - the previous value of the record is NULL when you're trying to insert. Correct it to use NEW and it should be fine

```
create or replace trigger trg_upd
 after update or delete or insert
  on dept for each row
 declare
 --pragma autonomous_transaction;
 begin
  if inserting then
  insert into deptemp values(:NEW.deptno,:NEW.dname,:NEW.loc);
  elsif updating then
 insert into deptemp values(:old.deptno,:old.dname,:old.loc);
 else
 insert into deptemp values(:old.deptno,:old.dname,:old.loc);
 end if;
end trg_upd;
```

Also, I really don't know why you're doing an INSERT under the UPDATING/ELSE branch conditions...